# Как обработать последовательность чисел и найти нужные пары

Tags: c++, int

В общем, на вход программе подаётся последовательность целых положительных чисел, не
превосходящих 30000. Признак конца ввода — ноль. Надо написать программу, которая подсчитает среди
введённых чисел количество пар, произведение элементов которых делится на 6. Под парой подразу-
меваются любые два из введённых чисел, не обязательно стоящие рядом.

Помогите пожалуйста, как это грамотно реализовать на C++, желательно без массивов, спасибо.

Comment: Считайте числа, делящиеся на 2, но не на 3, на 3 но не на 2, и на 6. После этого задача становится тривиальной... Надо только уточнить, считать ли пары (a,b) и (b,a) разными. И считать ли повторяющиеся числа одним и тем же. Например, в 2 3 6 6 сколько пар? 12? или 4? или 6?

Comment: Точно, спасибо!

Comment: Не забудьте также сосчитать числа не делящиеся на 2 и на 3.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку решения. Иначе его закроют.